# When Laravel Livewire get data to table from select event , 1st row edit button not showing after selecting

Tags: laravel-livewire

I used  wire.change event  to  get selected value in my   select input . Next that data got to the livewire controller and set it to the view . but the problem is after click 4 or 5 times  1st select option edit option row not showing .

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="card-body">
        <h1 id="Page_Header" class="text-md-center font_shadows_into_light">Leave Master
            Setup Details
        </h1>
        <div class="col-md-9">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row mt-3">
            <div class="row mb-3">

                <label for="company name"
                    class="col-md-2 col-form-label text-md-right Main_Lable"> Company Name :
                </label>

                <div class="col-md-9">
                    @isset($Companies)
                    <select class="form-control" wire:change='get_Leave_Data($event.target.value)' name="com_code" id="com_select">
                    <option value="null">Select a Company</option>
                    @foreach ($Companies as $company)
                        <option value="{{$company['ComCode'] }}">{{ $company['ComCode'] }} --> {{ $company['ComName'] }}</option>
                    @endforeach
                    </select>
                    @endisset
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-block" data-toggle="modal"
                    data-target="#exampleModal" id="Add_New_Leave" {{ $DisbleAddBtn === false ? '' : 'disabled' }}>Add New Leave</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row mt-4">
                <div class="form-group col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table table-striped text-center" id="mytable">
                            <thead class="thead-dark text-dark-50 bg-dark border-0 ">
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>REC.</th>
                                                <th>COM CODE</th>
                                                <th>LEAVE CODE</th>
                                                <th>LEAVE TYPE</th>
                                                <th>LEAVE DAYS</th>
                                                <th>LEAVE HOURS</th>
                                                <th>LINK</th>
                                                <th>STATUS</th>
                                                <th>Edit</th>
                                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                @isset($Leaves)
                                    @foreach ($Leaves as $leave)
                                    <tr>
                                        <td id="rec-id">{{$leave['RecUser'] }}</td>
                                        <td id="com_code">{{$leave['ComCode'] }}</td>
                                        <td id="leave_code">{{$leave['LeaveCode'] }} </td>
                                        <td id="leave_type">{{$leave['LeaveType']}}</td>
                                        <td id="no_of_days">{{$leave['LeaveDays'] }}</td>
                                        <td id="no_of_hours">{{$leave['LeaveHours'] }}</td>
                                        <td>
                                            @if ($leave['LinkToMain'] == true)
                                                <div class="form-check">
                                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="link_to_main" checked>
                                                </div>
                                            @else
                                                <div class="form-check">
                                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="link_to_main">
                                                </div>
                                            @endif
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            @if ($leave['Status'] == true)
                                                <div class="form-check">
                                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="status_button" checked>
                                                </div>
                                            @else
                                                <div class="form-check">
                                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="status_button">
                                                </div>
                                            @endif
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm editButton" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleEditLeave">EDIT</button>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    @endforeach
                                @endisset
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

here is the livewire controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class H01RosterMasterDetails extends Component
{

    public $Companies;
    public $Roster_Data;
    public $SelectedComapany ="";
    public $DisbleAddBtn = true;

    public function mount($CRTN_COMPANY){
        $this->Companies = $CRTN_COMPANY;
        $this->Roster_Data = [];

    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.h01-roster-master-details');
    }

    public function get_roster_data($SelectedComapany){

        if ($SelectedComapany != "null") {
            $this->DisbleAddBtn = false;
            $D_CRTN_ROSTER_DETAILS = app('App\Http\Controllers\H01_Roster_Master_Controller')->Fetch_Desig($SelectedComapany);
            if(!is_null($D_CRTN_ROSTER_DETAILS)){
                 $this->Roster_Data = $D_CRTN_ROSTER_DETAILS;
                }
            else{
                $this->DisbleAddBtn = true;
                $this->Roster_Data = [];
            }
        }else{
            $this->DisbleAddBtn = true;
            $this->Roster_Data = [];
        }
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: You should add `wire:key` to your looping elements, like `<tr wire:key="leave-{{ $leave->id }}">